# Error Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage

What I need

- I need to implement the bookmark functionality by toggling classes.

JS and HTML code

```js
var favoriteData = {};
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (localStorage.getItem("favoriteData") !== null) {
    $.each(favoriteData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favoriteData")), function(a) {
      $("#" + a).addClass("fa fa-heart");
      $("#" + a).removeClass("favourate_dextop");
      $("#" + a).removeClass("fa-heart-o")
    })
  }

  $(document).delegate(".favourate_dextop ", "click", function(a) {
    alert(a);
    favorite(this);
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-heart-o").toggleClass("fa-heart ")
  })
});

function favorite(a) {
  alert(a);
  if (favoriteData[a.id] !== undefined) {
    delete favoriteData[a.id]
  } else {
    favoriteData[a.id] = $(a).data()
  }
  $(a).removeClass("faved");
  localStorage.setItem("favoriteData", JSON.stringify(favoriteData));
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="icons_right pull-right">
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="dataLayer.push({'event':'addtofav'})" class=" fa-heart-o  favourate_dextop" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" id="fav3850" data-sess_id="3850" data-name="Ramadan and Eid Exhibition" data-city="Sharjah" data-country="United Arab Emirates"
    data-event_url="ramadan-fair" data-original-title="Follow &amp; Bookmark"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Problem

- When I click on heart icon it throws error `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`
- I have cross checked the script but i"m unable to find the error.

console.log(favoriteData)

```
   Object {fav74692: Object}
    fav74692: Object
    bs.tooltip: n
    city: "Graz"
    country: "Austria"
    event_url: "festival-senses-graz"
    name: "Festival of the Senses Graz"
    sess_id: 74692
    toggle: "tooltip"
    __proto__: Object
    __proto__: Object
```

Comment: Try using `console.log(favoriteData)` to see what's in it and why it has circular references.

Comment: You did that right before `localStorage.setItem`?

Comment: i have done console.log(favdata) before o/p: Object {fav74692: Object}
fav74692: Object
bs.tooltip: n
city: "Graz"
country: "Austria"
event_url: "festival-senses-graz"
name: "Festival of the Senses Graz"
sess_id: 74692
toggle: "tooltip"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object

Comment: Any idea where that `fav74692` sub-object is coming from? I suspect that's the problem.

Comment: its is id particular element ex <a id=fav74692>

Comment: how could i solve this circular json issue

Comment: Is there any other code that adds to `favoriteData`? I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: i have made jsfiddle it working fine but problem occurs in toggling class: http://jsfiddle.net/o61rqj95/5/